# Displaying notification badge like counter in UINavigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a requirement to display number of pending notifications in iPhone navigation bar. The appearance should be like that of notification badge - but these are not APNS notifications. They are the ones sent from private server with similar purpose.

I tried adding a right/left button (`UIBarButtonItem`) in my `UINavigationbar` but it seems like it is very rigid in appearance. I can't set its width, fonts etc. See my code:

```
  self.notifButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"0" style:
                    UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(TouchNotif)];

 NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 [items addObject:self.notifButton];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items;
```

Because of other 2 items also added to items array, navbar is cluttered. Their fonts, width etc I cannot play with, or maybe I don't know how should I create them.

My questions:

1) What is proper way to accommodate at least 3 items in navbar right area? I am asking this because I don't find a way to play with width and font of the `UIButtons` I use.

2) If I want to have custom appearance for my notification button (just like notification badge) - are there any pointers how do I make it? Which control to use, how to set its frame and font which will be allowed within `UINavigationBar`?

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a `UIBarButtonItem` that contains a custom view using `initWithCustomView`.
The custom view could be a custom UIButton with a number badge as subview. With this custom view you can also control the width of the buttons.

There is no public API to create a notification badge directly. In case of a tab bar item you could set a badge using the property `badgeValue` - but not with `UIBarButtonItem`.
Here you need to use this open source control: [MKNumberBadgeView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mknumberbadgeview).

Note that the property `rightBarButtonItems` is available since iOS 5.
If you only need one item set the `rightBarButtonItem` instead.

Comment: thanks and +1 too. InitWithCustomView worked. However after getting desired image I cannot set the title text of UIBarButtonItem. For example in my code when I do self.notifButton.title = @"my title" the debugger shows is correctly but the title is not visible on the image. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton * buttton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttton setFrame:CGRectMake(285, 20, 20, 20)];
[buttton.layer setCornerRadius:10];
[buttton setTitle:@"23" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[buttton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:buttton];
```

Answer (score -1):

First get the respective barbuttonitem in navigationController by

```
let baritem = navigationItem.right/leftBarButtonItem
baritem.badgeValue = "\(correspondingValues)"
```