# How to add splitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app(a sample app, upon success, gonna implement in my app) i am moving to viewController from my Appdelegate. In my ViewController.m, i am initialising a SplitViewController. But my code is not working.. I have given my appDelegate and ViewController codes..

**Appdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
PopMenuViewController *menuVC = [[PopMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *menuNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuVC];

PopMenuDetailViewController *detailVC = [[PopMenuDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopMenuDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

menuVC.detailViewController = detailVC;

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[menuNavController, detailNavController];

 //appdelegate.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 //appdelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

[appdelegate.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
}
```

Am not giving this code in AppDelegate because, in my real app, i need to implement splitviewcontroller concept only in my contacts page.. so i need to get splitViewController working when i click CONTACT button from my HOMEPAGE.. So can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SplitViewController should be at the root of the application. Instead of making NavigationController root view controller of the application , you should make SplitViewController its root.

My suggestion :
1. Learn more about SplitViewController. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).
2. Learn more about ViewControllers. Check this [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: SplitViewController should be at the root of the application. Instead of making NavigationController root view controller of the application , you should make SplitViewController its root.

Comment: Though if it can not be avoided then you are better off in doing self.view.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;

Comment: @Punnet: I need a common headerView to be added on the top of the splitViewController.. Can you pls help me on that ?

Comment: Common header as in? On all the View Controllers or only on the Master and Detail ViewControllers?

Comment: Actually a common header view need to be set on all pages(a header that has my company logo, contact number and things like that). But it would be fine to have it on the top of master and detail ViewControllers(common to them). so that i could implement it in all pages

Comment: I guess you are using everything inside a navigation controller. So you can actually make sure of its navigation bar. Follow this link to know how to include Label and UIImageView into the navigation bar

Comment: No link given in your previous comment friend.. I think i you forgot to add the link..

Comment: is it possible to have a header view on the top of the splitViewController Window? Am moving to splitViewController from viewController with ur code [self.view.window.rootViewController = splitViewController]; Is it possible to have a header view on top of this?

Comment: No, that way is not possible. Here is the link I was talking about:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890433/how-to-add-uiimageview-with-uilabel-in-navigation-bar-of-iphone